# SQLAlchemy: do not schema qualify columns in a select statement

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In SQLAlchemy, a query like

```py
user = sess.query(User).first()
```

will emit SQL with each column in the select clause qualified with the schema name

```sql
select
  myschema.user.id, -- (vs user.id)
  ....
from
  myschema.user
```

For some dialects, like Presto views, that is a syntax error.

Is there any way to make sqlalchemy skip the schema name in the columns of the select statement? e.g. `user.id` vs `myschema.user.id` without using `aliased` on every table? or a setting such that sqlalchemy automatically uses an alias?